# objective c cos sin returns different

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, math

I need your help in OS development. I have C# application which I converted to Objective-C. The iOS returns a different result:

Result in iOS:
GetHeading y: -0.000048
GetHeading x: -0.000087

[image: Expected result from C# here]

iOS source code:

```
double rlatitude1 = [self toRadians:startLocation.latitude];
double rlongitude1 = [self  toRadians:startLocation.longitude];
double rlatitude2 = [self toRadians:endLocation.latitude];
double rlongitude2 = [self toRadians:endLocation.longitude];
double y = sin(rlongitude2- rlongitude1) * cos(rlatitude2);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"GetHeading y: %f",y]);

double x = cos(rlatitude1) * sin(rlatitude2) -  sin(rlatitude1) * cos(rlatitude2) * cos(rlongitude2 - rlongitude1);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"GetHeading x: %f",x]);
```

iOS toRadiansCode:

```
+(double) toRadians:(double) degree
{
    double retVal = (degree * 0.0174532925);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"toRadians: %f",retVal]);
    return retVal;
}
```

[image: C# Source Code here]

Comment: FYI - don't use `stringWithFormat` with `NSLog`, it's redundant. Just do: `NSLog(@"GetHeading y: %f", y);`.

Comment: The result for `y` is the same. `-0.000048` and `-4.8E-05` are the same number.

Comment: use a break point to check the value of retVal rather, printing it with %f might be converting it to a float for printing

Comment: And replace the `0.0174532925` with `M_PI / 180`.

Comment: Replace `%f` with `%.15e` in the NSLogs.

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply... I went ahead with the debug mode and I'm having problems with this code on the next reply

Comment: double hc1 = sin(sLon - eLon);
            double hc2 = sin(boundaryHPoint.lon - eLon);
            if (hc1 != hc2)
            {
                hLoopCompleted = true;
            }

Comment: basically on .net c# values for hc1 and hc2 is equal to 1 (given same value inputs), on ios I'm getting a decimal value for hc1 = 0.002822996250424448 and for hc2 = hc2 double 0.0027102154306169212 0.0027102154306169212